# How is the Initiator Level of a Gestalt character calculated by RAW?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, dnd-3.5e, tome-of-battle, gestalt

Say you have a Martial Adept class on one side of your Gestalt and some other class on the other side, for sake of example let's go Rogue6//Swordsage6.  By RAI, I figure that the Initiator Level takes the higher of the two tracks for determining IL (in this case Swordsage) and thus would be IL 6.  However, to me it seems RAW actually doesn't clarify that at all.  In fact, the closest thing to it was Caster Level which doesn't factor in other classes in its calculation.

It seems to me that by RAW, due to how IL is calculated in general and the fact that you have 12 class levels total in this case (6 martial adept, 6 otherwise) your total IL would be 9.  Is this a correct reading of RAW or have I missed something somewhere?

Additionally, do the Pathfinder Path of War rules clarify or change this at all?

Answer (score 6):

> - Class features that two classes share (such as uncanny dodge) accrue at the rate of the faster class.

<sup>([*Unearthed Arcana*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/variant/classes/gestaltCharacters.htm#classFeatures) pg. 73)</sup>

Both rogue and swordsage grant swordsage initiator level, rogue at one every two levels, swordsage every level. You go with the faster one, i.e. swordsage, and end up with 6.

Comment: Do you have a source for this? Something along the lines of "If you gestalt with a class that lets you add your effective class levels to determine the effects of a feature, then you add those class levels as if you had multiclassed normally. For example, a 10th level sorcerer//wizard would have an effective caster level of 20th level."

Comment: @chif-ii Yes, the source quoted in this answer.

Comment: And that source would be...?

Comment: @chif-ii *Unearthed Arcana*’s rules for gestalt. I’ll update the answer with a citation in a bit.

Comment: @chif-ii Added a citation to both SRD and my print copy of *Unearthed Arcana*.